# Date in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a question regarding Java Hibernate and SQL

I want to add Date field to my entity class. I have used the following date format - 'yyyy-mm-dd' in my DDL script (data.sql)
Now I don't know which class to import for the date. Should I import **Date** from *java.util.** or from *java.sql.** ?

And which annotations should I add for this column

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use `java.sql` classes in your entities and try to avoid `java.util` ones as well. If you can use the `javax.time` ones.

Comment: Should I use javax.time?

Comment: @Column(name = "pub_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
     private Date pubDate;

Comment: I did something like this, but it shows an error in my SQL logs

Comment: Don’t use either `Date` class. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java.util.Date and annotation @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

import java.util.Date;

class Demo{

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

private Date dateField;

}

Answer (score 0):

1.Add another field in database (date_of_birth)

[image]

2. Add in your entity

   @Column(name="date_of_birth")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date dateOfBirth;
   with import java.util.Date;

[image]

3. add getter and setter

   public Date getDateOfBirth() {
   return dateOfBirth;
   }
   public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
   this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
   }
4. add it to toString

   @Override
   public String toString() {
   return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" +
   lastName + ", email=" + email

   - ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + "]";
     }

Answer (score 0):

Import **java.util.Date** in your entity and use **@Column** annotation only. In SQL, you can use column data type as DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Now, try to save the object. It will save.